# Selendroid "Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities"

Tags: java, android, ios, selenium, selenium-grid

I've got a problem with my selenium config. I'm trying to automate Selenium test on iOS and Android.

The iOS test are running correctly with iOS Driver independently.
The Android test are running correctly independently too.

But when i want to run iOS and Android i've got problems !

For my Android test, i was running this command and everything was fine :

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies.jar
```

But when i want to integrate iOS test, i change the port of this command, following this guide : http://selendroid.io/scale.html

But when I add -port 5555, my Android test fails. With this error :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities  [{automationName=selendroid, platform=ANDROID, platformName=android, browserName=android, serial=VM-IP}]

I start my config with the following command :

```
java -cp ios-grid-plugin-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT-4.jar:selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar:selendroid-grid-plugin-0.17.0.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher -role hub http://192.168.2.33:4444/wd/hub
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> Error forwarding the new session cannot find

is the Grid's way of telling you that you are trying to create a new browser session with a capability that the Grid is NOT aware of.

After starting the Selendroid server, did you run the CURL command as documented in [this](http://selendroid.io/scale.html) page

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @selendroid-nodes-config.json http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Doing this would now force the selendroid server to register itself to the grid running in local host and listening on "4444" and inform the grid that it can service android tests.

Without that, I don't think you can run your Selendroid tests in the Grid mode.

Comment: Problem solved. I was confuse in my port number. But now it's ok. How can i run test for various VM now ? I need to run multiple selendroid-standalone-server and specify one VM for one port ?